# Is DSCfix still needed/useful for multiplayer now that the game uses steamworks?

Tags: steam, dark-souls

The Steam version of Dark Souls has finally been upgraded to use steamworks. Praise The Sun!

What kind of mods are required to get multiplayer to work? So far, I only have DSfix installed and working and am so far not getting any multiplayer activity (not even orange soap signs).

In the GFWL days, I needed to install the DSCfix mod in order to get reliable online play. Is that still needed now that the game uses steamworks?

Comment: The hardest monster in all of Dark Souls was the one named "Games for Windows Live". I'm overjoyed to hear it's gone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSCfix is no longer needed thanks to the new steam servers! Durante did release [DSfix 2.3](http://blog.metaclassofnil.com/?p=652) which is all you will need now.

Comment: Although DSC fix isn't needed anymore wouldn't it be useful to have still? I haven't been having a problem getting basic multiplayer to work but I haven't been able to connect with my friends super easy like I used to in the dscfix days as well. Anybody know of anything in the works to help?

Comment: @Justin - DSCfix no longer works because it uses information based off the GFWL system. I've been (trying to) play the new steamworks version of the game and the connection system is even worse than it was before. You can pretty much only increase your ping limit and set your download server for steam to the same one your friend is using. I've downloaded DSCfix in an attempt to reverse engineer it, but I have to be honest with myself. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing :p